# Pass multiple but different variables/inputs through a function?

Tags: c, function

I would like to pass multiple different variables through one function that returns a single value/output.
The only way I can think to do this is to call the function for each value that needs to pass through it.

eg.

```
int foo = 9;
int doo = 4;
int yoo = 23;
convertIntToSomethingElse(foo);
convertIntToSomethingElse(doo);
convertIntToSomethingElse(yoo);
```

I've got a strong feeling this is bad programming and that there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: This is what arrays and loops are designed for.

Comment: What about passing an array of integers to function ? Or loop as sourav mentioned

Comment: Would it be too much to ask for an example?

Comment: But does the function need several variables to perform the task? or is it just a function which receives a number and returns whatever (another number), independently of the previous/next received value?

Comment: You can do this is several ways.  One would be to pass a null-terminated array of pointers to union structs that contains 'variant' data, tagged by an enum at the start that identifies the struct data type.  You could then iterate the list and switch on the tag type.

Comment: The function simply checks if any of the variables are negative integers, then converts them to positive, returning that value.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for an example.

There are 2 ways to do this:

First, is to pass the entire array to a function and then do things with those multiple times inside the array:

```
int yourArray[3] = {9, 4, 23};
//get the number of elements in the array by dividing total size by a 
//size of a single element
//if you know the size you can just use that, but it's not reccomended

size_t n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); //Pass this to function to get array size

void yourFunction (int a[], int sizeOfArray){

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<sizeOfArray;i++){
        //do stuff you need
    }
}
```

The second way is to just run the function multiple times in the array using a loop:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    yourFunction(yourArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: @4386427 Thanks, forgot about that! I changed the function so it takes the size as an argument. Do you know a better way to get size of passed array?